# How to create a fixed full-screen non-scrollable div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to mimic a typical modal. When a user clicks something, the modal shows up, with a transparent background that is full-screen and fixed.

Currently I have this:

```css
.thank-outer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="thank-outer" id="thankyou"> Some text </div>
```

The height of the div isn't the browser's height, but the full page content height, so it's scrollable.

How to change it so that the height of the div is just the browser's height?

Comment: Use the `vh` and `vw` CSS units, which correspond to the viewport-height and viewport-width respectively.

Comment: @Dai, I tried, the div is still scrollable...

Comment: You can try adding full size to the body instead,html, body {            height: 100%;            margin: 0;        }

Comment: normally a position fixed div with all offsets 0 will work for you. But if you are checking this from a mobile browser, it may be scrollable. is that the issue you face?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by setting the `body` element's `overflow` property to `hidden`.  This cuts off all elements that overflow off of the screen (and would make scroll bars).

```js
const $modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
const $button = document.querySelector('button');    

// Opening modal
$button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('modal-visible');
  $modal.classList.toggle('visible');
});
```

```css
body.modal-visibile {
  /* remove scroll bars when modal visible */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal {
  /* it is initially hidden */
  display: none;
  
  /* it will span whole screen */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;


  /* make it on top of all elements */
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: all;
  
  /* make the background white, but also with 80% opacity */
  background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.8);
}

.modal.visible {
  display: block;
}
    
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle Modal</button>

<h1>Some amazing content</h1>
<h2>Hopefully you enjoy this awesome content.</h2>
<p>Why are you still reading this? Just click the button!</p>

<div class="modal">
  <h1>It's a whole new world!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            margin:auto;
        }
        #thankyou{
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            background: rgba(222, 222, 222, 0.7);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="thank-outer" id="thankyou">
        Some text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my favorite pure CSS method to create a modal, still needs a bit of work for it to be 100% responsive but the basic skeleton is there.

The modal can contain elements and **clicking outside the modal will close it**. There's also a close button within it.

open in full screen for demo purposes.

```css
/* essential code */

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)
}

.closeoverlay {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closebutton {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.modal:target {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.modal:target>.closeoverlay {
  display: block;
}

.modal>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 75vw;
  max-height: 75vh;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #131418;
  z-index: 3
}

.wrap,
.modal {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}


/*demo fluff follows */

p {
  color: green;
  font-size: 20px;
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  display: block;
}

.minion {
  opacity: .7;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 50%;
}

button {
  margin: 2em 0 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.closebutton:hover {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clutter {
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    ;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#M"><button>Are you ready to enter the modal?!</button></a>
  <div id="M" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <a class="closebutton" href="#">&times;</a>
      <img class="minion" src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/b7a2e2b2d3a3a21ce6e38ee9f24d10a0/tumblr_nwivayrZFM1u95rdno1_400.gif">
      <p>Welcome to the modal!</p>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="closeoverlay"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clutter">Bacon ipsum dolor amet shoulder sausage rump venison kevin prosciutto salami shank. Venison salami flank doner burgdoggen, shoulder beef sausage swine alcatra short loin pig chuck. Pastrami sirloin shoulder, swine frankfurter beef strip steak sausage
  salami tri-tip. Prosciutto leberkas boudin pastrami sausage pork. Hamburger pancetta jowl venison pastrami. Filet mignon alcatra burgdoggen salami, ham hock shoulder pork loin sirloin jowl picanha flank drumstick pancetta. Turkey shoulder cupim rump
  ball tip strip steak turducken tri-tip biltong pork doner. Turducken leberkas chuck filet mignon bresaola picanha ball tip pig ground round shankle. Shank pork ribeye fatback, capicola pork loin tri-tip porchetta biltong landjaeger ham hock hamburger.
  Strip steak pork chop sirloin, tenderloin pork loin drumstick pig t-bone hamburger tail short ribs. Prosciutto burgdoggen leberkas landjaeger venison, meatloaf flank pork chop sausage bresaola tenderloin. Ham cow t-bone leberkas capicola turkey, jowl
  biltong chicken. Salami venison sirloin bresaola chicken. Ground round bacon chuck pastrami capicola tongue t-bone spare ribs leberkas. Short ribs beef andouille jerky shank ham hock. Rump hamburger boudin, short loin doner capicola cow spare ribs salami.
  Chicken hamburger strip steak filet mignon salami turkey doner frankfurter ball tip kevin porchetta andouille tongue cupim. Short loin bresaola pork chop porchetta pancetta. Sirloin burgdoggen ground round short loin corned beef cupim porchetta bresaola
  brisket leberkas pork chop. Leberkas salami cupim short loin prosciutto pastrami ham ground round strip steak bacon. Jowl brisket beef corned beef pancetta sausage pastrami shank swine. Tri-tip pork belly capicola ball tip tongue pork loin. Rump andouille
  swine, pig tenderloin tail hamburger ribeye short loin picanha leberkas porchetta ham beef pork. Biltong bresaola meatball shank tail andouille. Pig spare ribs short ribs ground round pork chop salami turducken.</div>
```